# C programming: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

I am writing in C this simple program, using xcode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double A[200][200][2][1][2][2];
    int  B[200][200][2][1][2];
    int  C[200][200][2][1][2];
    double D[200][200][2][1][2];
    double E[200][200][2][1][2];
    double F[200][200][2][1][2];

    double G[200][200];
    double H[200][200][2];
    double I[200][200];
    double L[50];



    printf("%d",B);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following message attached to  `printf("%d",B);`

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address= ….)
```

So basically is telling me that I messed up with the memory. How can that be possible?

BUT, if I comment

```
// int  C[200][200][2][1][2];
```

it works perfectly.

Any clue? It should not be a problem with Xcode since in Eclipse does not printf anything in any case.

Comment: stackoverflow......................have you taken this seriously and wanted to see if stackoverflow works......

Answer (score 3):

The default stack size on Mac OS X is 8 MiB (8,192 KiB) — try `ulimit -s` or `ulimit -a` in a terminal.

You have an array of doubles running at about 2.5 MiB (200 x 200 x 2 x 1 x 2 x 2 x sizeof(double)).  You have 3 other arrays of `double` that are half that size; you have 2 arrays of `int` that are 1/4 the size. These add up to 7.560 MB (7.4 MiB).  Even G, H and I are using a moderate amount of stack space: in aggregate, they're as big as D, so they use about 1 MiB.

The sum of these sizes is too big for the stack. You can make them file scope arrays, or you can dynamically allocate them with `malloc()` et al.

Why on earth would you have a dimension of `[1]`?  You can only ever write 0 as a valid subscript, but then why bother?

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments. You actually addressed the problem pretty well. It was a stack overflow problem (didn't know there was a limit to the stack). I allocated everything dynamically and it work perfectly.

Comment: This is the basic version of a huge dynamic programming problem. The dimension 1 is coming from a dimension that I typedef above (numbers you see here are all typedef in the original problem), but I wanted to simplify the example for the sake-ness of exposition. The %d was because I was printing B[0][0][0][0][0] (with similar result). I know I should have take it away, but I knew this had nothing to do with the final EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Therefore I was not caring. In any case you were completely right on the stack overflow. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure why you observe `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. But your code is quite broken. For a start, you pass `B` to `printf` and ask it to format it as an integer. It is not an integer. You should use `%p` if you want to treat it as a pointer.

The other problem is that your local variables will be allocated on the stack. And they are so big that they will overflow the stack. The biggest is `A` which is `sizeof(double)*200*200*2*1*2*2` which is 2,560,000 bytes. You cannot expect to allocate such large arrays on the stack. You'll need to switch to using dynamically allocated arrays.